# Why use 'advisor' or 'supervisor' instead of just 'collaborator'?

Tags: phd, masters, advisor, collaboration

This bugs me a bit. I understand that technically the advisor or supervisor relationship may be a bit different from the more senior-level collaborations, but I can't help but think when I see people say "thanks to my supervisors/advisors for their help with this project" (i.e. on Twitter press-releases of research, at the beginning/end of presentations at conferences) that it is a bit infantilising... I am not suggesting it is a particularly important problem, but from many PhD students I know and from my own personal experience, the supervisor role can certainly be very much equivalent to normal collaboration between other academics. I think it makes a PhD student sound more independent and capable if they were to refer to their co-authors on papers published during their PhD as their collaborators - even if they are in fact their supervisor/advisor.

Keen to hear others thoughts!

Comment: Advisors typically provide a very different kind of help than other collaborators (both quantity and quality) and identifying them as an advisor serves to acknowledge that.

Comment: I like this question. And I would love the term supervisor to be abandoned. It has become a weapon to exploit students. But then many PhD students are too naive to be qualified as collaborators.

Comment: I always had the impression that the choice of words between "advisor" and "supervisor" was mainly cultural; "advisor" seems to be prevalent here in the US, while "supervisor" seems more common in Europe.  Maybe it's just terminology, or maybe it reflects an actual difference in how advising/supervision works; I don't know.  Perhaps a different question...

Comment: @NateEldredge I would say an advisor is a student relationship. As a post-bacc employee, I probably would have called her my "supervisor," not my "advisor." Good q tho

Comment: I agree with @NateEldredge, but at least "my supervisor" is better than "my PI".

Comment: You're overthinking this. "Advisor" is the easiest/least awkward way to refer to your advisor, and people are generally aware of the fact that advisees have largely varying levels of independence.

Comment: @kosmos : 'supervisor' is a weapon to exploit students? That's quite a claim?

Comment: -1, this isn't really a clear question. Either someone is a collaborator - because both parties appear as authors - or they aren't. Put it this way: You wouldn't add a "thanks to my collaborator" as a comment at the end of a presentation. If indeed it were a collaboration, the entire work will have been presented as a collaboration. If not then sometimes you still want to thank/acknowledge someone's help. I don't know what you are getting at really.

Comment: Certainly in the many experiemental sciences, supervisor is more accurate than advisor, because the "supervisor" has various administrative and legal responsibilities for the student - for example, the supervisor would be legally liable if the student is injured in the lab or engages in scientific misconduct, and the supervisor generally controls the purse strings.

Comment: Collaborating is not necessarily a 2-way street where both lanes to at the same speed: almost all students collaborate with their supervisors, but not all supervisors collaborate with their students.

Comment: This seems more like a statement of the OP's opinion than a question.

Comment: While advisors/supervisors are collaborators, not all collaborators are advisors/supervisors. So, be specific.

Comment: In pure math, advisors are typically not even collaborators, at least not on all of the student's work.

Comment: T_M - Surprised to hear that you think it is unusual to thank your collaborators at the start of end of a presentation? I see this all the time. Very few people in my field (biology/ecology) conduct an experiment without significant help (collaboration) from others. I struggle to see what is unclear in the question. I am surprised people are saying they haven't heard this before - clearly I have or else I wouldn't have asked the question. If you think its a non-issue then I would say your expertise isn't relevant to the question, rather than the question itself being unclear.

Answer (score 25):

I think you're correct that the supervisor role can be equivalent to normal collaboration in that the student will bring their own unique ideas, knowledge, and experience to build on a mutual project collaboratively. However, where I think there is an unavoidable difference (at least, in every student I have met including myself) is the conception of viable projects. In my field I've never heard of a student (masters or PhD) conceiving from the ground-up their entire project. They're always built from a project advertised to prospective students, or developed with the supervisor (often from previous work) where a research relationship already exists.

As a student, you're learning to become an independent researcher. This means learning what is and isn't scientifically interesting and viable, how to search the literature and theory for relevant information, etc.. This is what a supervisor is teaching, and this is a very specific relationship that isn't properly conveyed with "collaborator".

This distinction is most important when there are multiple co-authors on a paper, including co-authors that are not the supervisor. The non-supervisor co-authors fit the description of collaborators and still should be described as such, no matter their academic "rank".

Comment: Indeed. The point of a PhD is to learn to be an independent researcher. Thus, by necessity, the PhD student isn't and independent researcher when they start. It is the job of the supervisor to guide the student on the journey from dependent to independent. Some students will be need more guidance than others.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree with what you have said. I have come across some people that have very much had a ground-up approach and I suppose that is where one contradiction appeared for me.

I suppose another element that spurred this is for a project I am doing I worked with what would be a 'collaborator' for much of a chapter of my thesis with my 'supervisors' doing far less actual supervising than the collaborator. Again, just seemed a contradiction that made me question the terminology.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think I have ever seen anybody ever "thank their advisor/supervisor(s)" (in a presentation or press statement) without explicitly name them.  One of the purposes of such a statement is to communicate the existence of a particular student-advisor relationship. There is a number of reason someone might want to do so:

- The relationship will immediately provide some additional context to the scientific work being presented for people in the community familiar with the advisor/supervisor.
- Acknowledging the relation provides appropriate credit to the advisor. This is particularly important when the advisor is a junior faculty, since the successful supervision of students is one of the criteria they are judged upon. Seeing students of a researcher appear at conferences plays a role in reshaping how the community views a junior researcher as a viable more senior candidate.
- The reputation of the advisor can be used as leverage to help people take a student more serious, especially when presenting research that is a bit "out there".
- The reputation of the advisor my help shield against some members of the audience being particularly nasty.

Comment: +1, The last point is actually two, a good advisor and his group will additionally already have roasted you with nasty questions before the conference, so you wouldn´t actually need him in the audience as a sentinel, but could defend yourself. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very interesting points - I agree that inheriting the reputation and using them as a human-shield is something unique to a 'supervisor' versus 'collaborator'!